# How to create a Java inner class correctly?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have the following java classes:

```
public class Outer {
 ...
 private class Inner {
  ...
 }
 ...
}
```

Assume I am inside a non-static method of `Outer`. Does it make a difference whether I call `this.new Inner()` or `new Outer.Inner()`? Is it, in the second case, guaranteed that no new `Outer` is created?

I have an annoying error in my program that appears only sometimes and is hard to find or to reproduce. So I am wondering if this line could make any problems.

Comment: If you declare an inner class it's basically because you won't use it anywhere else. But they still being different classes. If you instance an object of outer u wont need to declare an inner.

Comment: to avoid this `this.new Inner()` or `new Outer.Inner()`, you can declare your inner class as `static` class. `private static class Inner`

Comment: I believe the two constructor invocations you posted are functionally identical (it would be a different matter if you had written `new Outer().new Inner()`. But wouldn't it be more helpful for your search to post the error you are trying to resolve?

Comment: Thank you, that was the main question whether these two lines are semantically identical. But I think that is a question of knowing the Java standard and not "believing", isn't it? :-)

Comment: If I don't resolve my error, I can post it, but that is too hard to explain because I don't know in which line of code it appears.

Comment: You can ask yourself: how would it even theoretically be able to create another `Outer` instance? Since you do not specify its constructor parameter it is not possible that a custom constructor will be invoked and therefore not possible another `Outer` is created.

Comment: @Kolodez You don't know in which line the compilation error occurs? Compilation errors always specify the line, so that doesn't sound right.

Comment: That was no compilation error. The problem was unexpected program behavior. But I finally found the problem. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the same, though they are both unnecessarily long-winded.

The following 3 versions results in the exact same bytecode:

```java
class Outer {
    private class Inner {
    }
    void foo() {
        Inner a = this.new Inner();
        Inner b = new Outer.Inner();
        Inner c = new Inner();       // Recommended way to write it
    }
}
```

*Bytecode*

```java
       0: new           #7                  // class Outer$Inner
       3: dup
       4: aload_0
       5: invokespecial #9                  // Method Outer$Inner."<init>":(LOuter;)V
       8: astore_1

       9: new           #7                  // class Outer$Inner
      12: dup
      13: aload_0
      14: invokespecial #9                  // Method Outer$Inner."<init>":(LOuter;)V
      17: astore_2

      18: new           #7                  // class Outer$Inner
      21: dup
      22: aload_0
      23: invokespecial #9                  // Method Outer$Inner."<init>":(LOuter;)V
      26: astore_3
```

<sup>*Blank lines added to improve clarity.*</sup>

Comment: `new Outer.Inner();` is sometimes usefull when instantiating an inner public static class from somewhere else. I think of it like an additional package / scope qualifier.

Comment: @RetoHöhener It is good that you think that, because that's exactly what it is. Similarly, `this.new Inner()`, or rather `other.new Inner()`, is useful when you want the `Inner` object to be linked to an `Outer` object *other* than `this`, which is similar to how you can access a field using `name` or `this.name`, you can write `new Inner()` or `this.new Inner()`, makes no difference.